# Are there any plugins in vscode to make code segment can be previewed in the minimap when i hover my mouse?

Tags: visual-studio-code

just like the plugin "minimap-lens" in Atom editor

link: https://atom.io/packages/minimap-lens

Comment: AFAIK the mouse events of the minimap are not available to extensions in VSC

Comment: ok~ thanks! (a little disappointed)